# Convexity on a real normed space

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $C$ be an open convex set in a real normed space $(E, ||.||)$, which contains $0$ and $x \in C$ if and only if $-x \in C$.

It means that $\forall x \in C, tx \in C, t \in (0,1)$.

We define: $p(x) :=$ inf $( \alpha > 0 : \alpha ^{-1}x \in C)$, for $x \in E$.

I want to show that $C = (x \in E : p(x) < 1)$.

I guess I have to show the double inclusion, but when I look at my drafts, I'm not sure $C$ is well defined by the function $p(x)$. Shouldn't it be $C = (x \in E : p(x) > 1)$, instead ?

This does not seem correct to me, or at least I don't get it. Any help here please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p(x)$ is a measure of how much the ray starting from $0$ and going through $x$ is inside of $C$. If $p$ is small, there is some $\alpha$ arbitrarily close to $p$ such that $\alpha^{-1} x\in C$. Since $\alpha$ is small, $\alpha^{-1}$ is large, so a "big" chunk of the ray is inside $C$.

To prove $C \subset (x \in E : p(x) < 1)$, consider $x\in C$. Since $C$ is open, there is some $\epsilon >0$ such that $x+\epsilon \frac{x}{\|x\|}\in C$, hence $p(x)<1$.

To prove $(x \in E : p(x) < 1) \subset C$, consider $x\in E$ such that $p(x)<1$. There is some $\beta\in ( \alpha > 0 : \alpha ^{-1}x \in C)$ such that $\beta <1$. Then $\beta^{-1}>1$ and $\beta^{-1}x \in C$. Since $0 \in C$, the segment going from $0$ to $\beta^{-1}x$ is inside $C$. The segment contains $x$, hence $x\in C$.

Comment: It's very clear.Thank you !